# Uploading files from a client folder through a Asp .Net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I know that most of the modern browsers do not support 'Folder level' selection because of obvious security risks. But, I know they support 'File level' selection. So, if I select a file from a client side folder, truncate the file path to get the folder path, and upload files from that folder using

```
DirectoryInfo
```

or some other class, behind the scenes? I am currently using ActiveX to achieve this functionality, but would like to move away from it. If this is not possible what are best alternatives to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

modern browsers *do* support directory uploads.

```
<p>Directory: <input type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory /></p>
```

[here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Z4Amr/107/)

Comment: This is supported only in Chrome. Doesnt work in IE or Firefox.